# how to get data from hyperlink in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck trying to retreive categories `id` from a hyperlink in HTML5. First I have parsed a JSON link in HTML5 using jQuery.

My code:
HTML code: 
jquery code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getJSON('http://'    '/storejson.php', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.items) {
            output += "<li>" + data.items[i].categories_name + " " "</li>";
        }
        output += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<a href="http://'     '/storesubcatjson.php?cat_id=&cat_id"><div id="placeholder" align="justify"></a>
```

I have given a hyperlink to placeholder like above. Categories are shown by parsing JSON but I want to show subcategories through hyperlink. So please tell me how can I acheive this?

Comment: Where do you want your `subcategories`? You will have to modify the `php` so that it can give you back subcategories.

Comment: You can try `console.log(data);` to see if the data contains `subcategories`.

Comment: i want subcategories in next page by clicking categories name

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the href from the a tag by 
then pass link to your getjson when clicked or however best suits you and that will send the request to the php file, but keep in mind your php file has to also be set up to grab parameters passed in the url string from the href.

```
         <script>
    var link;

 $("a").click(function(){link = $(this).attr("href")}); // get this inside a click event on the 'a' tag
     alert(link);// to see the url being passed
    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
             var output="<ul>";
             for (var i in data.items) {
             output += "<li>" + data.items[i].categories_name + " " "</li>";
       }
       output += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
 </script>

 <a href="http://storesubcatjson.php?cat_id=&cat_id">CLICK</a> // If you click here it should send the href data
```

Comment: u use var link and that 'link' is also used in  $.getJSON(link, function(data)but i have to give json url in $.get json function() when i use this mean it also show subcategory of categories and also parse json category url   i have two url one is  jsoncategory and json subcategory..

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand what you mean in the last comment

Comment: hey plz tell me t want to show subcategories through hyperlink when i click on categories it will show cat _id in url and display subcategories. i have parsed json url by using jquery but how can i pass parameters from hyperlink to display subcategories i have subcategory url that is http://' '/store/storesubcatjson.php?cat_id=&cat_id this a hyperlink..

Comment: If you have the url, you should just send the request to the php file and then update placeholder with the results of the php file

Comment: i have tried ur code but no result only show CLICK WHEN I CLICK I SHOW HYPERLINK    CODE:var link;

 $("a").click(function(){link = $(this).attr("href")}); // get this inside a click event on the 'a' tag
     alert(link);// to see the url being passed
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/store/storejson.php', function(data) {
             var output="<ul>";
             for (var i in data.items) {
             output += "<li>" + data.items[i].categories_name + " " "</li>";
       }
       output += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});

Comment: did you change the put in the correct href in the a tag? I have modified it because I do not know your full url that you need to request

Comment: i have two url that is http://example.com/store/storejson.php first i have parsed it contain categories.. second url "http://example.com/store/storesubcatjson.php?cat_id=&cat_id which i give  href also included <div id="placeholder"></div>

Comment: but how we pass cat-id in jquery or html